# span css help IE7 - How can I set the width?

Tags: css, html

I have this CSS and I cannot set the width on a span element. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
#address-readonly
{
  margin-left:150px !important;
  padding-left:100px;  
}
```

I am using this in 2 areas in my application. Here is the first area:

```
<tr>
  <th colspan="2">Address Details</th>
  <th><span id="address-readonly" class="address-readonly"></span></th>
</tr>
```

And here is the second area:

```
<div id="addressHeader" class="addressHeader">
<span>Address Details</span>
<span id="address-readonly" class="address-readonly"></span>
```

I want the `address-readonly` span to be more right aligned. The padding/margin combo has almost no effect. What should I be doing here? I don't want to add a bunch of non-breaking spaces, but that's basically the effect I am looking for. This particular client has an office full of IE7 machines, so no FireFox or Safari etc... I have tried setting the width of the span as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#address-readonly
{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 100px; /* If you want to set the width */
}
```

or you could use a div and not set the display attribute.

Comment: I found this answer helpful. +1

Answer (score 0):

If applicable, you could try using `display: block`:

```
#address-readonly {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Without floating, the span will be on it's own row. Hope that helps.

Comment: What I think the OP wants to accomplish is simply increasing the horizontal distance between the two spans. Your solution would break them vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice is a `display` value of `block` or `inline-block`, because `inline` elements are resized by their content. Also, please note that `inline-block` is not that well supported.

Answer (score 0):

Guillaume's and Wicked Flea's answer complement each other, but some points are missing.

Only "box elements" can have its width/height attribute set. Span is a inline element, so it will resize it self to fit content.

So, if you want your elements to have width set, you should use a box element. The problem here is that box elements do not line up in the same row by default. You can then use float and margins to align a box element with another box element.

All that being said, it would be good to use Guillaume's answer. BUT some quirks may appear, check this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) link about clearing floats.

What would I do: Use the workaround presented in the link, then use both spans as divs, and have them floated to the left, with your widths and paddings set.